# Need help with inverse trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

How can I prove $\arccos\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ is equal to $2\arctan x$ for $x\geq0$ ?

I am also supposed to use the fact that if a function is defined and differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $f '(x) = 0 \forall x \in(a,b)$ then $f$ is a constant in $(a,b)$.

Comment: Hint: take cos$^{-1}(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})=\theta$ and then proceed by taking cos of both sides.

Comment: You can also calculate the derivative of the both functions to check if they are equal. Then evaluate the both functions at any point (say $x=0$ for example) to see that they are still equal. It may allow you to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

let $$t = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right), x \ge 0.$$ 
that tells two things: (i) $0 \le t \le \pi,$  and (ii) $\cos t = \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}.$

using $\sin t = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 t}$ we find $\sin t= \frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$

we will compute the ratio $\frac{1-\cos t}{\sin t} $ in two different ways.
$$\frac{1-\cos t}{\sin t} = \dfrac{1- \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}} = x.$$

and $$\frac{1-\cos t}{\sin t} = \frac{2\sin^2 t/2}{2\sin t/2 \cos t/2}=\tan(t/2).$$

we have $$\tan t/2 = x \text{ and } t = 2\tan^{-1}x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arctan x=y\implies -\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\pi\le2y\le\pi$

$\arccos\dfrac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}=\arccos(\cos2y)$

$\arccos(\cos2y)=2y$ iff $0\le2y\le\pi\iff0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: For $\arctan x = y$, the inequality should be strict:  $$-\frac{\pi}{2} < y < \frac{\pi}{2}$$ since $\tan x$ is undefined if $x = (2n + 1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: The link you cited confirms what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you let $\displaystyle f(x)=\arccos\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)-2\arctan x$, $\;$ then

$\displaystyle f^{\prime}(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)^2}}\left(-\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)-\frac{2}{1+x^2}$

$\;\;\;=\displaystyle \frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^2-(1-x^2)^2}}\left(\frac{4x}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)-\frac{2}{1+x^2}$.

Now simplify to show that $f^{\prime}(x)=0$, and that $f(0)=0$.